# PictureCallback gets byte[] data in 'onPictureTaken' but it doesn't match the image I see in CameraView.

Tags: android, image, opencv, android-camera, face-detection

I am using opencv face detection in my android app.The problem I am facing is as follows. My class which implements 'PictureCallback' gets byte[] data in 'onPictureTaken' but it doesn't match the image I see in CameraView. Image is been cut from right.

I am showing received bitmap in simple ImageView.

Note: It has nothing to do with my ImageView or XML layout. As I can verify the issue with the image I save on sdcard.

I would highly appreciate if someone can help me in this regard. Unable to figure it out that what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks
regards

Answer (score 1):

Android camera has two independent settings: **previewSize** and **pictureSize**. They may have different aspect ratios, too. E.g.

```
previewSize=1920x1080
pictureSize=4200x2800
```

The camera does not distort the image, it crops it.

If you want to keep the same field of view in your captured picture as you have on your viewfinder screen, you should choose same aspect ratios for both. Even this does not guarantee that the capture will keep exactly same field of view (e.g. due to focus adjustments).

Note that you must choose the preview size and picture size supported by your camera. Android API includes *[getSupportedPictureSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes%28%29)* and *[getSupportedPreviewSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes%28%29)*.